# How to add a specific number of days (+1 day) to current date in (ISO & RFC format) for "WordPress"?

Tags: wordpress, addition, days

I have been searching for a long time to find out how easily to add a specific number of days (+1 day) to current date in (ISO & RFC format) for "WordPress"?

Anyway, After tons of testings and failure I came up with the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

First of all, We must get the default current post date **(get_the_date)**, Then add the desired format **(ISO or RFC)**, and finally increase it by adding more +days to it as follow:

```
<?php
$Date = get_the_date('Y-m-d');
echo date('c', strtotime($Date. ' + 10 days'));
?>
```

**The results will be:**

```
 - Current date: 2018-09-14
 - Increased date: 2018-09-24T00:00:00+00:00 *(with ISO format)*.
```

This achievement can be useful when you want to validate sitemap, Wordpress feed, or add schema markup to your pages (manually).

**Hope this can help you :)**